# Dividing two columns in a dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below dataframe:

```
|module     | name  |value |
|-----------|-------|------|
|node[11]   | x     |4.0   |
|node[11]   | y     |1.0   |
|node[2]    | x     |2.0   |
|node[2]    | y     |3.0   |
|node[21]   | x     |6.0   |
|node[21]   | y     |6.0   |
```

and would like to create a new dataframe that contains the value (x/y) for each module. so the expected output would be

```
|module     | out   |
|-----------|-------|
|node[11]   | 4.0   |
|node[2]    | 0.66  |
|node[21]   | 1.0   |
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just do `pivot` then calculated what your need

```
out = df.pivot(*df).eval('x/y').to_frame('out').reset_index()
Out[23]: 
     module       out
0  node[11]  4.000000
1  node[21]  1.000000
2   node[2]  0.666667
```

Comment: Wonderful answer. Can you please tell what does `(*df)` mean inside df. Or more specifically what does `*` do when used with `df`

Comment: @MuhammadHassan equal to df.pivot(index= modile, coluns='name', values= 'value'), * is list unpack ~

Comment: oh got it, but will this work if I have more than three columns ? Here as we had three columns so when we did `(*df)` we had one for `index`, one for `columns` and one for `value` but what if we had more than three columns?

Comment: @MuhammadHassan More than 3 will not work